# scala circe encoders/decoders for an abstract class with case classes

Tags: scala, circe

I want to save a collection of FieldMapping classes as a json string -

```
abstract class Field {
  def clazz: Class[_]

  def name: String
}

case class StringField(name: String) extends Field {
  override def clazz: Class[_] = classOf[String]
}

case class DateField(name: String) extends Field {
  override def clazz: Class[_] = classOf[Date]
}
```

... etc - full code here:
https://github.com/alexeyOnGitHub/scala-typesafe/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/example/model/Field.scala

Circe code:

```
import com.example.model.{DateField, Field, FieldMapping, StringField}
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.{deriveDecoder, deriveEncoder}
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder}

object CirceBoilerplateForConfigs {
  implicit val fieldDecoder: Decoder[StringField] = deriveDecoder[StringField]
  implicit val fieldEncoder: Encoder[StringField] = deriveEncoder[StringField]

  implicit val dateDecoder: Decoder[DateField] = deriveDecoder[DateField]
  implicit val dateEncoder: Encoder[DateField] = deriveEncoder[DateField]

  implicit val fooDecoder: Decoder[FieldMapping] = deriveDecoder[FieldMapping]
  implicit val fooEncoder: Encoder[FieldMapping] = deriveEncoder[FieldMapping]
}
```

> Error:(14, 65) could not find Lazy implicit value of type
> io.circe.generic.decoding.DerivedDecoder[com.example.model.FieldMapping]
> implicit val fooDecoder: Decoder[FieldMapping] =
> deriveDecoder[FieldMapping] Error:(14, 65)
>
> not enough arguments for method deriveDecoder: (implicit decode:
> shapeless.Lazy[io.circe.generic.decoding.DerivedDecoder[com.example.model.FieldMapping]])io.circe.Decoder[com.example.model.FieldMapping].
> Unspecified value parameter decode.   implicit val fooDecoder:
> Decoder[FieldMapping] = deriveDecoder[FieldMapping] Error:(15, 65)
>
> could not find Lazy implicit value of type
> io.circe.generic.encoding.DerivedObjectEncoder[com.example.model.FieldMapping]
> implicit val fooEncoder: Encoder[FieldMapping] =
> deriveEncoder[FieldMapping] Error:(15, 65)
>
> not enough arguments for
> method deriveEncoder: (implicit encode:
> shapeless.Lazy[io.circe.generic.encoding.DerivedObjectEncoder[com.example.model.FieldMapping]])io.circe.ObjectEncoder[com.example.model.FieldMapping].
> Unspecified value parameter encode.   implicit val fooEncoder:
> Encoder[FieldMapping] = deriveEncoder[FieldMapping]

Comment: In your gist you didn't provide code for `GUser`.

Comment: `FieldMapping` is also not defined.

Comment: If I comment out `case class GUserField`, `def user`, `import com.example.model...`, `implicit val fooDecoder`, `implicit val fooEncoder` everything compiles.

Comment: here is the rest of the code - https://github.com/alexeyOnGitHub/scala-typesafe/tree/master/src/main/scala/com/example/model    I need encoders/decoders for FieldMapping collections because this is what I want to convert to a json string

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Field` should be a sealed trait (with abstract class or not sealed trait this won't work).

The following code compiles:

```
import java.util.Date

sealed trait Field {
  def clazz: Class[_]

  def name: String
}

case class StringField(name: String) extends Field {
  override def clazz: Class[_] = classOf[String]
}

case class DateField(name: String) extends Field {
  override def clazz: Class[_] = classOf[Date]
}

case class FieldMapping(fieldInConnector1: Option[Field],
                        fieldInConnector2: Option[Field],
                        selected: Boolean,
                        defaultValue: String)

import io.circe.generic.semiauto.{deriveDecoder, deriveEncoder}
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder}
object CirceBoilerplateForConfigs {
  implicit val stringDecoder: Decoder[StringField] = deriveDecoder[StringField]
  implicit val stringEncoder: Encoder[StringField] = deriveEncoder[StringField]

  implicit val dateDecoder: Decoder[DateField] = deriveDecoder[DateField]
  implicit val dateEncoder: Encoder[DateField] = deriveEncoder[DateField]

  implicit val fieldDecoder: Decoder[Field] = deriveDecoder[Field]
  implicit val fieldEncoder: Encoder[Field] = deriveEncoder[Field]

  implicit val fooDecoder: Decoder[FieldMapping] = deriveDecoder[FieldMapping]
  implicit val fooEncoder: Encoder[FieldMapping] = deriveEncoder[FieldMapping]
}
```